# SQL Server Management Studio 17 cannot find one or more components

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I have just upgraded to Visual Studio 2017 Professional and SSMS 17.

I can access my servers and databases through Visual Studio 17's SQL Server Object Explorer but when I try to execute SSMS outside of the VS IDE it tells me "*Cannot find one or more components.  Please reinstall the application*".  I have reinstalled SSMS 17 twice and still cannot run it.

The SSMS executable is at:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe`.

I get the same problem on another machine running VS 2017 Community.

What is causing the message "*Cannot find one or more components.  Please reinstall the application*" when I try to execute SSMS outside of Visual Studio?    What do I need to do to execute SSMS outside of the VS IDE?

Comment: SSMS 17 was *released* yesterday. Did you install it just now and found a problem? Or did you install an RC version? BTW I have VS 2017, 2015, SSMS 16 and 17.0.  installed. I had 17 RC3 up to now. The only problems I get appear when I open VS 2015 before SSMS . Dismissing the error screens and reopening SSMS takes care of the errors

Comment: I installed SSMS 17 yesterday.  It was not the RC.

Comment: After uninstalling and reinstalling a collection of VS components and SSMS the problem has disappeared.  So I can confirm VS Professional 2017 and SSMS 17 work fine together.  In some respects through your example Panagiotis you provided the answer - thanks, why don't you mark it up?.

Comment: I got the same error message on Friday, using 17.1.Dismissing and reopening did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 204):

I had similar problem and in my case it was due to a corrupt `Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Isolated)` which SSMS 17 requires to run outside the VS IDE.

To fix this, I had to do the following:

1. Uninstall `Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable` (both the x64 and x86). This is to ensure that step (2) will succeed as the repair process of the prerequisites might fail in some cases if newer versions have been installed.
2. Repair `Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Isolated)` (or reinstall using  https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/9/C/C9CA8400-20AA-4488-92A3-F3F6D978AD81/vs_isoshell.exe).
3. Reinstall `Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable` (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746572 and https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746571) if removed earlier.

Comment: How did you figure this out?

Comment: Pretty much trial and error. Checking and reinstalling the possible dependencies one by one.

Comment: @roberto Followed these instructions after installing .NET Core 2.0 on my machine, which appears to have broken SSMS 17. Worked perfectly, thanks.

Comment: Just in the interest of saving time, I was able to skip step 1 and just repair 2015 Shell. This answer helped so much though, these prerequisites are killer sometimes.

Comment: I wish I could upvote more than once ! Very helpful answer. Thank you very much !

Comment: In my case I had to re-download the isolated shell. It took forever to find the download link so here it is for everyone else: https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/9/C/C9CA8400-20AA-4488-92A3-F3F6D978AD81/vs_isoshell.exe

Comment: worked like a champ! thanks for saving me a ton of time, was on the verge of repaving my box after multiple uninstall/reinstall/repair attempts on SSMS itself.

Comment: Step 2 solved SSMS 2017 crashes at startup. This problem occurs after remove VS 2015 and installing VS 2017 .

Comment: This worked, but I did have to perform one additional step: restart my workstation.

Comment: Installing the Redistributables in Step 3 solved it for me, apparently they weren't installed in the first place!?

Comment: To add to this - I had errors installing vs2015 shell in step 2 and the solution was to clean temp folder and temporarily disable my antivirus - then repair it's installation via add/remove features.

Comment: In my case, the sql server version is 2014. Which version of VS shell (Isolated) should I install. I remember I have uninstalled a 2010 (isolated) something.

Comment: @马化腾 SSMS 2014 uses VS 2010 shell. You can download it here: https://vspartner.com/pages/vsshells?id=1366

Comment: Just occured with SQL 2017 Developer and SSMS alongside the usual Visual Studio 15.8, SSDT 15.8 and SSMS 15.8. 2015 runtimes were not visible only "tools for applications": Removing the isolated shell and the two (x86/x64) tools for applications then doing an SSMS repair fixed the problem, thanks! I tried everything before even removing and repairing the whole 2017 VS but of course it's the old VS 2015 shell that 2017 VS would never reinstall which was the culprit! They should recompile SSMS with 2017 shell to get rid of this risk and modernize.

Comment: Gotta love MS's super helpful "Cannot find one or more components" error message.

Comment: I uninstalled all MS visual C++ redistributables, did step 2, but fyi for anyone else, step 2 reinstalled MS V C++ redist. 2013 & 2015, and I did not need to reinstall 2017+ versions, and VS 2019 and MS SSMS runs fine now. "Note Visual C++ 2015, 2017 and 2019 all share the same redistributable files."

Comment: Installing `Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Isolated)` worked for me. I had uninstalled it in my case.

Answer (score 59):

> Here is a quick fix for **cannot find one or more components** in **SQL Server**

Follow these steps:

1. Run **Add or remove programs** (Type into run box)
2. Repair **Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Isolated)** (Modify > Repair)

The installation process will report that it was unable to install some of the Visual C++ executables as they are already present; this message can be ignored, the repair still fixes the problem reported in the question.

Comment: I don't know how you figured it out but it worked for me.  Much simpler than other fixes.

Comment: This works great. Didnt have to touch the vc++ redistributables separately - the vs2015 shell repair (which fixes this issue) does indicate that it didn't complete successfully because the vc++ installations are already there, but that can be ignored.

Comment: Installing `Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Isolated)` worked for me. I had uninstalled it on my PC.

Answer (score 8):

For SSMS 2017 delete this folder from the registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\14.0_Config
```

> It would be better to export the keys before deleting them.

Comment: Works perfectly.

Comment: Did not work for me.  This was SSMS 2017 after VS 2017 was installed.

Comment: i had this issue in lower versions of ssms and it really wasted my time. I am glad it worked for some of you. This bug is not related to installing VS 2017.

Comment: did not work for my sql server 2014. Should I restart my computer?

Comment: This config is not for SQL Server Management Studio 2014 its for 2017. You should import keys back if ssms 2017 works perfect and delete different version.

Comment: reinstall isolated shell , vs reinstall did not work for me. but this did the trick

Answer (score 4):

Same steps as Roberto's solution above - but updated links:

**1. Uninstall:**

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x86) - 14.xxxx
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x64) - 14.xxxx
```

**2. Repair or Download/Install:**

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Isolated)
```

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/isolated-shell/

**3. Reinstall:**

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x86) - 14.xxxx
```

https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x86.exe

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x64) - 14.xxxx
```

https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe

Answer (score 4):

For everyone that is coming here in 2022 and has Windows 11 (build 22622.440) installed, this is your reason> [Missing components for Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Shell (isolated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72797415/missing-components-for-microsoft-visual-studio-2017-shell-isolated?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Disable the sv2 nav pane from experimental features from windows!

> **Download https://github.com/thebookisclosed/ViVe**

Run vive tool from elevated cmd with the option to disable the experimental feature:

> **vivetool /disable /name:SV2Navpane**

Restart windows immeadiatly:

> **shutdown -r -t 0**

Taken from here, thanks to @Erin Stellato: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/6b7d06dc-9bec-ec11-a81b-6045bd7ac9f9

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I accidentally uninstall Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Isolated) and I got the error "SQL Server Management Studio 17 cannot find one or more components". even though I recover or Repair Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Isolated), the same error was there.

- **The only thing I did was reinstall Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Isolated).** I **did not** Uninstall Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (both the x64 and x86).
  this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running SSMS 18 and every time KB5014770 installs, I get this error. If I uninstall this upgrade (KB5014770) it starts working again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove every version installed of visual C++, then run the repair on the Visual Studio 2015 Shell (isolated). Once completed, open the SQL Server Management Studio and it will work.

Comment: I've tried every fix on this page. None has fixed SSMS 17 for me and the last one broke 2012. Now I have NO working version of SSMS. :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was corrupted because the drive that it was installed on originally was removed as part of a drive consolidation exercise. That is to say, it was installed on E:\ but E:\ no longer existed.

I managed to resolve by using VSubst (https://www.ntwind.com/software/utilities/visual-subst.html) and creating a fake drive pointing back to C:\ (run as admin) where there was a "fresh" install of 2015 after downloading the VS 2015 ISO.

I then re-ran the uninstaller, which fails, then inside the log file, on the first line is the path to the "old installer". Now if you run a {PathInLog}\vs_isoshell.exe /uninstall /force with the E:\ created it will force uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and solved very easily. Normally SSMS will look for integrated application. This integrated is installed by default during SSMS setup installation.

I can say your error "Cannot find one or more components.  Please reinstall the application" caused because  some application is uninstalled or missing by anyhow. To open SSMS will look for some connected integrated application.

Please follow these steps:

1. search "shell" in Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features
2. uninstall any "shell" application
3. Download from Microsoft below application.
   "en_visual_studio_2015_shell_isolated_x86_dvd_XXXXXXXX"
4. Run the application and allow all application to install during the process.
5. Once everything is done. Restart your system.