# I can't install SSMS 2017

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2017

I had installed the application but once I opened it it says that:

> Cannot find one or more components. Please reinstall the application.

I had uninstalled the application for a lot of times but the error still exists. I tried to download VS2015 Powershell but once I run it, it just flashes.

Comment: Are you attempting to install SSMS (Sql Server Management Studio) or Microsoft Sql Server? What kind of a machine are you attempting the install on (OS, Memory, CPU, Virtual/physical, ...)? The more details that you can provide the better. Also, if you are installing SSMS, are you installing this on a box that already has Microsoft Sql Server installed?

Comment: I am trying to install SSMS 2017. I am installing it to my laptop, Windows 10, 2GB RAM, I have a lot of free space. I don't think I had SSMS in my laptop since I reformatted it

Comment: Have you attempted to get a new copy of the installer in case your copy has been corrupted in some way? Sounds strange, but I have unfortunately seen that happen in the past.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43807502/sql-server-management-studio-17-cannot-find-one-or-more-components

Comment: @halfer I am very sorry. Its just that I have a project due tomorrow and I can't install SSMS

Comment: OK. Please remember that folks here are volunteers, and they will help you if they have time.