# Missing components for Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Shell (isolated)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssms

Today I wanted to open Sql Server Management Studio 18 like every day. But this time an error message popped up:

> Cannot find one or more components. Please reinstall the application.

And I reinstalled the application and even reinstalled the Microsoft visual studio 2015 Shell. What also confuses me is the fact that the shell 2017 of visual studio does not even exist yet. I'm working on a windows 11 machine.

Comment: I had exactly the same happen about an hour ago, again windows 11. So far I have tried everything from the result from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43807502/sql-server-management-studio-17-cannot-find-one-or-more-components but nothing works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a reported issued on Windows 11 22H2 (22621).
See https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/6b7d06dc-9bec-ec11-a81b-6045bd7ac9f9

Answer (score 1):

After I uninstalled all Microsoft related Softwares in the control panel and reinstalled all again the SSMS started working. I just found out that you can also use Azure Data Studio as an alternative for SSMS, which is also sometimes preinstalled on windows machines.

**EDIT**

There is a solution provided in the forum that I'd like to share here:

1. Download https://github.com/thebookisclosed/ViVe
2. Run (from elevated cmd prompt):

```
    vivetool /disable /id:36354489
    shutdown -r -t0
```

In my case it returned `No features were specified` why I used another command:

```
    vivetool /disable /name:SV2Navpane
    shutdown -r -t0
```

Comment: Sadly, uninstalling all MS software isn't really practical, even if I don't actually strip down to bare metal.

Answer (score 1):

If you're currently enrolled in Windows Insider Program and using Beta Channel,a fix for this issue was released just recently.

[Windows 11 Insider Preview Build 22621.586 and 22622.586](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2022/08/24/announcing-windows-11-insider-preview-build-22621-586-and-22622-586/)